# Storing data.tables in a list with a for loop in R - Issue with linked references

Tags: r

I have a data.table of data in year 1, and I need to increment the year by 1, and recalculate the columns in the data.table for 25 timesteps. I will need to access the datable from each year, and so am trying to store this in a list.

When I do this, I end up with the same data.table stored 25 times. Some other posts have mentioned that this is because of the list being reference based, but I cannot work out how to implement a solution.

```r
lst_assets[[1]] <- df_assets_loop_start

for (i in 1:params$n_timesteps) {
    lst_assets[[i+1]] <- lst_assets[[i]][, age := age + 1]
}
```

How do I alter this loop to store 25 unique data.tables?

Comment: Hello! welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some more information to your question. ```de_assets_loop_start``` and ``params``` are named in your code. But we can't see/know what is in it.  Without a Minimal Repoducable Example (MRE) it is very hard to understand what is going on and write a good answer.

Comment: You should probably `rbindlist` your data.tables into one data.table.

Comment: I'm a big fan of data frames in lists, but  I don't see a need for lists here. One big data.table with a `timestep` column, and operations grouped by `timestep` seems much simpler.

Comment: Each future timestep needs to take the changes in all previous timesteps into account, and I wasn't confident that grouped operations would preserve this for me. 

e.g. I need to replace the top n rows until the sum of one column is reduced by a specific quantity determined by the change since the last timestep. This feels more like for-loop territory to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed to do with updating by reference. You will need to copy the object to do it in a loop, e.g.:

```r
lst_assets[[1]] <- df_assets_loop_start

for (i in 1:params$n_timesteps) {
    lst_assets[[i+1]] <- copy(lst_assets[[i]])[, age := age + 1]
}
```

However, as Roland suggests in the comments, you probably do not need a loop to do this - and copying the entire object negates a lot of the speed benefits of using a `data.table` rather than `data.frame`.

If you take up Omniswitcher's suggestion of providing more data then it will be easier to suggest another way of doing this.

**Example with dummy data using rbindlist assuming each data.table has same number of rows**

Here is how you could do it with rbindlist, assuming each `data.table` has the same number of rows:

```r
# Create dummy data
dt  <- data.table(x = 1:10, age = 1)

# Repeat it 25 times in a list
num_iterations = 25
dt_list  <- lapply(1:num_iterations, \(.) dt)

# Bind it into one data.table
dt_joined  <- rbindlist(dt_list)

# Increment age (assuming each dt has same number of rows)
dt_joined[, age:= rep(1:num_iterations, each = nrow(dt))]
```

**Example with differing numbers of rows**

If each `data.table` has a different number of rows you can do:

```r
# Create dummy data
set.seed(10)
dt  <- data.table(x = 1:10, age = 1)

# Repeat it 25 times in a list - with differing numbers of rows
num_iterations = 25
dt_list  <- lapply(1:num_iterations, \(.) dt[1:sample(1:nrow(dt), 1),])

num_rows  <- sapply(dt_list, nrow)
# 9 10  7  8  6  7  3  8 10  7 10  2  8  8  7  6  7  6  2  5  9  2 10  5 10

# Bind it into one data.table
dt_joined  <- rbindlist(dt_list)

# Increment age
dt_joined[, age:= rep(1:num_iterations, num_rows)]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - The loop is necessary for later calculations that need to be done, so I would need to separate the single year either way, and I think it is more readable to build the list year by year. I needed to bind it into a single data table afterwards, so thank you for predicting my need for that!